# Perform Action IF the active sheet is one of a group of sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clear rows in a worksheet.

I found `ActiveSheet.Range(range).Clear`.

I have similar looking worksheets in the workbook and I am trying to protect myself from accidentally deleting stuff I need.

I am trying to check if the active sheet is one of 7 worksheets in the workbook. If it isn't, don't clear.

```
If Not ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets("014").Name Then

Else
    ActiveSheet.Range("40:42").Clear
End If
```

This works for a single worksheet, but I need to check for 6 more sheet names. I can code this with multiple "IF NOT" statements checking for each sheet, but is there a shorter, cleaner way to check all seven worksheet names in the same "IF NOT" statement?

Comment: yup, put the sheet names in an array and iterated through that array and test  If any are found then exit the sub.  Or use INSTR and put all the names in a string and test if the name is in the string.

Comment: There is no point in testing `ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets("014").Name`.  Instead, you should just use `ActiveSheet.Name = "014"`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you. I'm self taught and still learning so I'm not sure I completely understand what you are saying.

Comment: @OpiesDad Thank you. As I was trying stuff out this worked, so I went with it. Learning anything to make thing simpler is always appreciated.

Comment: Here's a simple explanation of arrays: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/array.html.  Then just make a loop and go through it.  The other option Scott recommended is this `If InStr("sheet1,sheet2,sheet3,014,....",ActiveSheet.Name) <> 0 Then`  Just put all of the sheet names in one long string and search in the string for the one you are checking.  Of course this only works if there aren't sheet names that are a substring of other sheet names.

Comment: Thank you both VERY much. I was able to get it to work with the INSTR function. I will look into the arrays option when I have more time. How do I mark as answered and give you guys credit?

Comment: You can't really.  We left it as a comment instead of an answer.  I'll put it in an answer if you want to accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all of the sheet names into one string and then use that.

```
Dim strSheetNames as String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
strSheetNames = ",Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3,014..," 'include all sheet names
If InStr(strSheetNames,"," & ws.Name & ",") <> 0 Then
      ws.Range("40:42").Clear
End If
```

The comma searching trick is per Zev Spitz.

Comment: You could append commas to the beginning and end of `strSheetNames` and also to the second parameter passed to `Instr`: `strSheetNames = ",Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3,014,": If Instr(strSheetNames, "," & ws.Name & ",") <> 0 Then`. The only issue with this is if the sheet name has a comma in it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a Scripting.Dictionary to hold the names of the sheets you are interested in checking against:

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
dict.Add("Sheet1", 1) 'the actual values don't matter; we want to check against the keys
dict.Add("Sheet2", 1)
dict.Add("Sheet3", 1)
dict.Add("014", 1)
```

Then we can check if the key exists in the dictionary:

```
If dict.Exists(ws.Name) Then
    ws.Range("40:42").Clear
End If
```

---

You could also use an array:

```
Dim sheetNames(4) As String
sheetNames(0) = "Sheet1"
sheetNames(1) = "Sheet2"
sheetNames(2) = "Sheet3"
sheetNames(3) = "014"
```

but since there's no built-in way to check for the existence of an item in the array, you have to write such a function yourself:

```
Function ContainsItemm(col As Variant, item As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim x As Variant
    For Each x In col
        If x = item Then
            ContainsItem = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

and use it thus:

```
If ContainsItem(sheetNames, ws.Name) Then
    ws.Range("40:42").Clear
End If
```